# PHP: SSL HTTP Authentication?

Tags: php, security, http, authentication, ssl

I have a php page in which I have the following code to validate the user using HTTP authentication, this code works fine for `http://` url's but when I use the same page with `https://` then it didn't ask for username and password.

```
//authentication settings
define('USERNAME', 'prashant');
define('PASSWORD', 'password');

//Validating
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Authentication required"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Unauthorized access';
    exit;
}else{
    if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != USERNAME && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != PASSWORD){
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Authentication required"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Unauthorized access';
        exit;
    }
}
```

What's the problem and how I can resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is your server set up to serve https:// URLs from the same document root? If you try to access a normal `helloworld.php` with just an echo() in it through SSL, does that work?

Comment: Yes, my server have the SSL enabled and the same URL works with http and https both.

Comment: Try close browser, open it again and open https page.

Comment: @Riateche it works. Thanks..!! 

as its just a browser issue what should I do now. Should I close this question or let it be open so others can get help?

Comment: Wow, it's been 8 years and nobody answered you? Sorry! Definitely close it as **off topic because** then **it can no longer be reproduced**.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the problem and how I can resolve this?

As the comments on this question already addressed, it was caused by browser caching the HTTP authentication details for your domain. Closing then re-opening the browser with HTTPS solves the problem.